# How to make a general navbar in emberjs?

Tags: ember.js

How can I add general navbar for the whole app without having to repeat myself by adding it to all the routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in the `application.hbs` template, since that is the root template of your application and will be shown for every route.

Comment: And generally you'll just inject a service into your navbar, if it is a component. So would you want to update the title dynamically or what not, you can just update a title property in the service.